# Timedelta Conversion is incomplete

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I've been trying to work around the data type in my data frame. I have a column that measures duration in this format "HH:MM:SS". I have converted the data to timedelta type, and values above 24hrs e.g, "335:44:07" are not converting to days as I expect, rather is parsed as NaT. Please how do I make "335:44:07" to display as "13 days 09:44:07"?

Answer (score 0):

conversion should work from scratch using [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['335:44:07'])

pd.to_timedelta(s)
```

from a DataFrame:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'])
```

output:

```
0   13 days 23:44:07
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: it works on string but not the column, still parses as NaT

Comment: @Jen what is the exact format? Can you provide a sample?

Comment: This is the [dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kGBUS2OXmNETIAMZ9qGL-taxVD04QoO2/view?usp=sharing), and this is the [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N2g3UFJbCLHFwnJlYOttPNA91l8O2_F5/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
print (pd.to_timedelta(["335:44:07"]))
TimedeltaIndex(['13 days 23:44:07'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

For column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['335:44:07']})
df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta(df["col"])
print (df)
               col
0 13 days 23:44:07
```

EDIT: After many comments problem was in original column `col` was missing values, so converting to timedeltas generate missing values `NaT`.

Comment: it works on string but not the column, still parsing as NaT

Comment: @Jen - What is `print (df["col"].head(10).tolist())` ?

Comment: [here please](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CqlS6xo8zExGrDJBulBuuPUa17mOYy-K/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Jen - do you send me data before `df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta(df["col"])` ?

Comment: @Jen - Problem is in input data are missing  `NaT` and if parsing to timedeltas got `NaT` ?

Comment: This is the [dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kGBUS2OXmNETIAMZ9qGL-taxVD04QoO2/view?usp=sharing), and this is the [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N2g3UFJbCLHFwnJlYOttPNA91l8O2_F5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: On the original data frame, the 'col' was an object type, so I converted to timedelta, then it parsed some of the values correctly and left some as NaT. I filtered out the null values from the original data frame, and tried to execute with the code you suggested. Then it gave that output I just sent to you.

Comment: @Jen - I am really confused with ouput. I need filter values before `df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta(df["col"])`, not after by test missing values. If need filter rows in original DataFrame by missing values generated `pd.to_timedelta` need `out df.loc[pd.to_timedelta(df["col"]).isna(), 'col'].tolist()[:20]` - test in original

Comment: and then need `print (out)`

Comment: is this better ? [print out](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1upxk1NxpTk8mqqLHXMSE-mTW-NIjTOmU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Jen - so it means in original DataFrame are missing values? check `df[df["col"].isna()]`. So missing values after pd.to_timdelta are again missing values `NaT`

Comment: okay, I get it now. Thanks a lot, I appreciate the time

Comment: @Jen - added to answer ;)